# Files with "core" name

Tags: files, filenames, core-dump

Can I be sure that files with name `core` on the system are core dump files? Or how can I be certain about some files that they are core dumps to delete them? (best practices are welcome)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Or how can I be certain about some files that they are core dumps to delete them?

Use `file` to check this. It prints `core file` if your file is a core file:
For example:

```
> file ./core.17511
./core.17511: ELF 64-bit LSB core file x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from './main'
```

This is what `man file` says:

> file tests each argument in an attempt to classify it.
>
> The type printed will usually contain one of the words text (the file
>   contains only printing characters and a few common control characters
>   and is probably safe to read on an ASCII terminal), executable (the
>   file contains the result of compiling a program in a form
>   understandable to some UNIX kernel or another), or data meaning
>   anything else (data is usually 'binary' or non-printable).  Exceptions
>   are **well-known file formats (core files,** tar archives) that are known
>   to contain binary data.